# Не могу поставить Windows 7 после Ubuntu с флешки

Tags: windows-7

Вроде как всё идёт, загрузка первая, но меня смущает больше графическая оболочка загрузчика: она вся размазанная и пиксельная, как будто драйверов что ли не хватает или ещё что-нибудь. Почему так? Это нормально? Ставил на виртуалку в Ubuntu - всё ок, видно как надо, картинка чёткая и  не размазана. Подскажите, почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1):

Это нормально, потому что драйвера на видеокарту придется установить после инсталляции Windows (в дистрибутиве нет подходящих драйверов, для вашего устройства)

Comment: Поддерживаю. В Ubuntu шли драйвера "из коробки". Эти дровишки сами по себе не очень (что не удивительно, ведь делают их не производители видеокарты), поэтому можно поставить дрова от производителя, они будут получше (но обычно со своими заморочками тоже). А Windows не дает никаких драйверов из коробки, поэтому сразу приходится лезь после установки на сайт производителя видеокарты и там уже скачивать и устанавливать.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что, во время инсталляции *windows*, идёт определение оборудования, на которое ставится система. Чтобы была возможность работать с оборудованием сразу после установки, разработчики добавили драйвера для всех устройств в установщик. Итак, во время установки, идёт определение оборудования, и установка драйверов для него.

*Так как производителей устройств и моделей оборудования, огромное множество, то все драйвера для всех устройств просто физически не поместишь в установщик. Получиться огромный размер дистрибутива winodws. Поэтому разработчики и сделали грубо говоря несколько универсальных драйверов. Получается после установки устройство работает, но часть возможностей недоступна*